# Google Maps does not navigate when I use AirPods

Tags: iphone, audio, bluetooth, airpods, google-maps

When I use AirPods or Bluetooth headsets, Google Maps does not navigate by sound.

I don't know why, but if I disconnect the Bluetooth and use the iPhone speaker, everything works well.

I searched the internet for a remedy, but nothing worked.

Does anyone know of a fix for this?

Comment: Which iPhone?  Which model of AirPods?  What version of iOS?

Comment: I am using iPhone 13 with the 16.4.1 version and Airpods 2 with latest version

Comment: Did you ensure that the Google Maps Audio is unmuted and that your AirPods volume is on?

Comment: @JBallin Sure, I tested it many times. It will work well when I turn off connect with Airpods or bluetooth headsets

Comment: To clarify - it works for me, so I'm guessing it's something on your end.